# Pandas appending to a csv file overloads memory

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm sending ~330k api requests to an API that returns JSON. I'm batching the requests into groups of 10k, then trying to append that response of 10k requests to a csv file so that I end up with a CSV with 330k rows. Currently, when I try to append to the csv file, memory usage increases for every 10k rows, but I thought it would be linear given I'm starting the loop again every 10k rows. Is there a way to optimize this?

**Code to loop through each chunk of 10k**

```
with open(r'data.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        #chunk is 10,000            
        for i in chunk:
            await loop_handler(i, session, csvfile)
```

**Write to CSV**

```
loop_handler(my_list, session, csvfile):
    # Create a list of tasks
    tasks = []

    # Append each task to our tasks list
    for link in my_list:
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(get_single_req(session))
        tasks.append(task)

    # asyncio.gather focuses on gathering the results. It waits on 
    futures and returns their results in an order
    my_data = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    df = pd.DataFrame(my_data)

    df.to_csv(csvfile, index=False)
```

Comment: Where is your `all_pg` list being populated?  It looks like you are creating a dataframe using an empty list and then appending that dataframe to your csv file.

Comment: @j_b you're right apologies - just updated the question to reflect how it works.

Comment: Ok, with that change in mind, your CSV file is open for appending all 330k records at one time.  Have you tried moving the csv opening inside your loop so that the csv file is opened and written to for each 10k chunk only?

Comment: @j_b yes I tried that and the memory usage and time it takes remains more or less the same.